# Why is Microsoft's Managed Stack Explorer not showing Windows Services?

Tags: .net

When I run the [Managed Stack Explorer](http://mse.codeplex.com/) I don't see any Windows services running. Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comments [here](http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2009/05/managed-stack-explorer-net-2335-ie-clr.html): you need a 64 bit version which can be found [here](http://artisticcheese.blogspot.com/2010/04/managed-stack-explorer-compatible-with.html).

(to all those wondering why I answered my own question, see [this Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to))